# What about std::array storage placement?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I want to have mechanism that allows me to concatenate variadic function parameters (all of them are convertable into value of some specific plain-old-data type `F`) into a raw data storage of appropriate size (size is greater than or equal to sum of parameters sizes). I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

template< typename F >
struct repacker
{

    constexpr
    repacker(F * const _storage)
        : storage_(_storage)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_pod< F >::value, "Underlying type is not a POD type.");
    }

    F * const storage_;

    template< typename... P >
    auto operator () (P && ...params) const
    {
        constexpr auto N = sizeof...(P);
        using A = std::array< F, N >; // using A = F [N]; this eliminates the problem
        static_assert(sizeof(A) == sizeof(F) * N, "This compiler does not guarantee, that this code to be working.");
#ifndef _NDEBUG
        auto a =
#else
        std::ignore =
#endif
                new (storage_) A{F(params)...};
        assert(static_cast< void * >(a) == static_cast< void * >(a->data()));
        return N;
    }

};

int main()
{
    using F = double;
    constexpr auto N = 6;
    F * a = new F[N];
    {
        F x(1.0);
        F const y(2.0); 
        repacker< F > r(a);
        auto const M = r(x, y, 3.0, 4, 5.0f, 6.0L);
        assert(M == N);
    }
    std::copy(a, a + N, std::ostream_iterator< F const & >(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    delete [] a;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I am not sure that the `assert(static_cast< void * >(&a) == static_cast< void * >(a.data()));` assertion is true for all the compilers. This is a necessary condition for a code to be working.

Is it always the assertion is true?

Comment: I find the solution of key problem: `using A = T [N];`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/R9Nua6z0 here is final version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is a necessary condition for a code to be working.

No, it is not. OK, it is necessary, but it is not *sufficient*. Another necessary condition for this (very terrible) code to be working is:

```
sizeof(std::array<F, N>) == sizeof(F) * N;
```

And that is *not* guaranteed by the standard. `std::array` is not layout-compatible with C-style arrays. The *contents* of `std::array` are, but not the full type itself.

If you want to initialize some object in memory you allocate in blocks of bits, you should new up a `char[]` array, not an array of `F`. You should allocate this:

```
char *a = new char[sizeof(std::array<F, N>)];
```

Comment: But [This struct has the same aggregate type semantics as a C-style array. The size and efficiency of array<T,N> for some number of elements is equivalent to size and efficiency of the corresponding C-style array T\[N\].](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: @Dukales: The *standard* doesn't guarantee that, no matter what that website says.

Comment: @Dukales: No, it has the semantics of an aggregate class containing an array. Classes are allowed to add padding after any member, and the standard doesn't guarantee that the array is the only member, so the size of the class may be larger than that of the array.

Comment: What if storage is always aligned as `F` and packed?

Comment: @Dukales: The ***standard*** doesn't guarantee that. So now you're not talking about the standard; you're talking about the specific implementation-dependent behavior of a specific implementation.

Comment: Could you give the way (to save a parameters into a continious memory region)?

Comment: @Dukales: Have you considered `std::vector`? Also, why do you *want* to?

Comment: I'm writing the compiler (string expression into the directly executable code). The class, that encapsulates the code and data storage (same for both), have a member function, that calls this code. Some of parameters of "main" function (is necessarily present in the code) are "external", i.e. global. I should to place they values into storage (aligned as `F`) before call. Addressing is RIP-relative, so I must place all parameters by value.

Comment: @MikeSeymour the standard guarantees that the member array (or its other contiguous equivalent) is the only non-static data member (via the requirement to be an aggregate with no more than N initializers). I agree on the formally allowed trailing padding though.

Comment: @Cubbi: Yes, I realised that it did guarantee that it was the only member just too late to correct my comment. I hoped no-one would notice.

Answer (score 4):

@AndyProwl pointed out something very important:

`std::array` is guaranteed to be an aggregate as defined by C++11 8.5.1/1:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equalinitializers for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

Let us test that against C++11 9/7:

> A *standard-layout* class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference
>
> [...]

Violationg this is easier than one might expect:

```
struct violator { virtual ~violator () { } };

typedef ::std::array<violator, 2> violated;
```

Here the type `violated` would have a data member that is of type array of a non-standard-layout class.

Therefore the guarantee expressed in C++11 9.2/20 (that allows reinterpreting a pointer to the class as one to its first member, and is as far as I can see the only passage in the standard that might make your assumption valid) does *not* hold in all cases for `::std::array`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure point 1 is not guaranteed, because `std::array` is supposed to be an aggregate so that it can be initialize by doing `std::array<int, 5> arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. If `elems` were not the first data member, this would not work

Comment: Yikes, good point, somehow I skipped that part and assumed it was legal to implement it as a intializer_list constructor.

Comment: I liked my example, now the answer is boring :(

Comment: I know the feeling, happened to me a lot of times!

Comment: @AndyProwl It proved to be far less boring than I expected, since aggregate types have pretty strong requirements.

Comment: Right, now it is nice and complete :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Standard layout types guarantee that you can convert a pointer to them to a pointer of their first member using `reinterpret_cast`. IIRC `reinterpret_cast` can potentially return a different address than used as input (due to alignment restriction).